# Twitter JS file issue

Tags: html, twitter, socialshare

I am trying to create a Twitter Share button in my Website. My code is like below

```
<li>
    <a href="{! $request->url() !}" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large">Tweet</a>
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</li>
```

I am getting output like below

[image]

I found Twitter button is placed little upside. If I remove the `JS` file `<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>` then it is placed perfectly.

I searched a lot in Google but did not get any solution.

Do you know what is the solution ?

Comment: Sounds like a rendering issue which is browser-specific. Perhaps the script tag is showing some kind of proportion, which is offsetting the nearby twitter-link

Comment: Thanks @admcfajn. What is the solution ?

Comment: @admcfajn, I tried with CSS but could not find any solution. Do you have any tutorial to create Social Share button ?